# minted - how to highlight html also, when language "twig" is selected

Tags: minted, html, syntax-highlighting

I use `minted` and I try to format `twig`-Code. But when I select `twig` as the code-language, it does highlight the twig code but it **doesn't highlight html**-code!

This looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to select two (multiple) languages or **is there any way to have the minted package highlight `html` also, when `twig` is selected?**

Answer (score 2):

`pygments` provides two different lexers for Twig code. The first one is a simple regex lexer `twig` which only parses the Twig parts of the code. The second one `html+twig` is a delegating lexer which uses the `twig` lexer for the Twig parts and the `html` lexer for the HTML parts of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\texttt{twig}:
\begin{minted}{twig}
{% for message in app %}
    <div class="message">
        <b>{{message}}</b>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
\end{minted}

\texttt{html+twig}:
\begin{minted}{html+twig}
{% for message in app %}
    <div class="message">
        <b>{{message}}</b>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]